# How to generate counterexamples for modal logic trees from Girle

Tags: modal-logic, truth-tree

I am having a heck of a time understanding a counterexample discussion in Girle 2000. Here is the tree:

[image: Lines 1-9 of a tree from Girle 2000 p. 28]

[image: Lines 10-12 of a tree from Girle 2000 p. 29]

But then, on p. 40, Girle reads off the tree:

[image]

I understand where the values in *k* and *l* come from. The *k* values come from lines 7 and 11. The *l* values come from lines 8 and 12. But I do not understand where the values for *n* come from.

PS - If you have Girle 2009, the tree is on pp. 28-29, and the counterexample reading is on p. 42.

Comment: Right, yes, so lines 1-6 are all in n—but how do you get that p and q are both false in n from those lines?

Comment: At n we know p and q are both (only) possible from line 2 and similar modal judgement from line 3, we cannot infer they are both false at n from those lines, at most either of them is false per line 4 at k or l (see line 9, 10 at the bottom of the tree)...

Comment: Hmm. That is what I thought. But then why does Girle report 0 for both p and q in n? Sorry to keep coming back—I would have left that column blank, or put question marks, because I read the tree like your last comment suggests (I believe).

Comment: This is because right above your table the author mentioned "*w has access to no world... at once false in w*"...

Comment: Isn't that saying that if w has access to no world, then diamond claims are immediately false? But n has access to two worlds, k and l. And in any case, it isn't that everything is false—it is that diamond claims are false. But here the table seems to say that p and q are themselves false, and not just possibly false, in n.

Comment: Can you add the screenshot after this table to provide more context since above are many pages away? Notice on the first one it's a wonderful S5 tree. My take is to find a counterexample for this in S5 you only need 2 worlds (the table columns of k and l), your table shows a worst case where at most one needs 3 worlds to find such a counterexample if unluckily starting from such n world distribution...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right that the values for p and q at world n are in fact arbitrary - they could be 0 or 1. What Girle is doing is proving that there is a counterexample to the original sentence, by showing that there is an open path in the truth tree. The open path in the diagram corresponds to p holding at k, ¬p holding at l, q holding at l, and ¬q holding at k.

This open path exists irrespective of what holds at n. But for completeness, Girle is exhibiting the counterexample as a triple of values, i.e. the values of p, q at all the worlds n, k and l. He happens to show the values of p and q at n as 0. The triple with p and q at n as 1 would just be another counterexample. But we only need one counterexample for the proof to work.

I agree the text could be a little clearer.

Comment: Thanks! This is clear and helpful!